# The concern is not Almah or Behtula!

Tags: matthew, isaiah

The Almah or Behtula on Isaiah 7:14 is well debated (and clear) here BUT I would like to bring the more important issue out of this which personally I thinks many might have missed out:

> This all happened so that what was spoken by the Lord through the
> prophet would be fulfilled: “Look! The virgin will conceive and bear a
> son, and they will call him Emmanuel,” which means “God with us.”
> Matthew 1:22‭-‬23 NET

Ignoring the "virgin" issue. If Matthew is of Hebrew origin, he would not be mistaken about the "Virgin" word and will not quote from Isaiah, which will make people of that time immediately know he misquoted the holy scriptures, which only available at their time.

Only logical conclusion that Matthew:

1. is not of Hebrew origin and misunderstood the holy scriptures (Hebrew illiterate) and quoted from it
2. is not divine inspired to write this
3. on intention to fool illiterate Hebrew of that time, and draw then away from Worship God of Israel, introducing "foreign idea" against God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob

Unless there are better explanation of why Matthew deliberately write such a grave error that might give 'his identity' or 'ill intention' away.

My apologies that I might not express my thoughts skillfully over a pen.

Edit as directed by mod:
My question is: How trustworthy is Matthew's records of his account on the gospel if such mistake is grave? Are we to accept whatever has been presented without questioning? (Hope the mod can accept my question?)

Comment: The NT is in Greek and used the GREEK scripture aka LXX Septuagint. This word is derived from the greek parthenos, thus the concept of virgin birth also came from a misguided interpretation of parthanon concept. Greek was the default popular mainstream bible for them as we have English today. Your que is very misguided.

Comment: to avoid having the question closed you should probably rephrase it so that it is a question.

Comment: and make it less "opinion-based."

Comment: The error is in the virgin birth interpretation not in the word from LXX.

Answer (score 1):

Several points in response to the request for a better explanation than Matthew's supposed ignorance and/or his willful intent to deceive illiterate Hebrews.

1. He could have based his understanding on the Septuagint (Greek) OT rather than the Hebrew. The Alexandrian Jews who translated Isaiah into Greek were highly educated and knew that "almah" means young unmarried woman not "virgin." But they translated the term as "parthenos," which does mean virgin. In this scenario, Matthew might have known both the Hebrew and the Greek versions of the prophecy and simply conflated them. After all, nearly all maiden girls of Isaiah times were also presumed to be virgins.
2. The story of the Virgin Birth may have been told to Matthew (or whoever wrote the Gospel that goes by his name) by others. Like the story of the Empty Tomb, which he also did not witness, he was a faithful believer and presumed both stories to be true. In this scenario, Matthew didn't invent the story but reported it. It could be that he added the bit about Jesus' birth fulfilling Isaiah's prophecy, or that the story was was related to him with the prophecy as part of the legend.
3. Matthew often interpreted prophecy loosely. For example Jesus returned from Egypt to fulfill the prophecy "out of Egypt I called my son." (Hosea 11:1; Matthew 2:15) But Hosea is talking about the nation of Israel, not the Son of God. Similarly, Jesus settled in Nazareth to fulfill the prophecy that "he shall be called a Nazarene" (Matthew 2:23) But there is no such prophecy in the OT. So Matthew's use of "virgin" instead of "maiden" is consistent with his emphasis on events in Jesus' life fulfilling prophecy. Some might call this deceptive but there is little reason to doubt that Matthew himself believed these to be prophecies fulfilled.

**OP argues that Matthew's supposed ignorance of Isaiah's Hebrew prophecy means that this part of the scripture is not divinely inspired. This is not necessarily the case. For Christians inclined to the doctrine of verbal inspiration, it is a matter of faith that God inspired the Gospel writers, regardless of the objections of skeptical readers. For others, inspiration is understood in a more general sense. God uses human instruments to convey the Gospel, and human beings do not always hear God's word with perfect clarity.**

Comment: Helpful answer to a poor question. +1.

Comment: i am not sure if greek Septuagint is during or after (supposed) Matthew time? Matthew is written and based on academic to be AD60-130 period. Not sure if greek Septuagint BCE285 is available for Matthew as reference.  the wiki shows that only the first 5 books is translated...

Comment: It was widely read among those Jews who spoke Greek, including Paul. But there are arguments both ways as to whether Matthew (and Matthew's Jesus) quoted scripture from the Septuagint or the Hebrew. https://www.i.bible/behind-the-scenes/the-septuagint/